# Consume WEBAPI PUT Method in asp.net web form using values from textbox

Tags: asp.net

This is the code in my Helper Class

```
public static async Task<string> PUT(int id, string name, string code)
{
    var inputData = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"name", name },
        {"code", code }
    };

    var input = new FormUrlEncodedContent(inputData);
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage res = await client.PutAsync("http://197.253.124.132:84/api/Departments" + id, input))
        {
            using (HttpContent content = res.Content)
            {
                string data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                if (data != null)
                {
                    return data;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return string.Empty;
}

public async void btnproperties_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var response = await RestHelper.PUT(txtid.text, txtname.text, txtcode.text);
    lblmessage.Text = (response);
}
```

I  am new to WEBAPI and and trying to consume a PUT method in WEBAPI using values of textboxes controls on my asp.net web form.Below is what i have tried. But not working.

Below is the error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>. This exception may also indicate an attempt to call an "async void" method, which is generally unsupported within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the asynchronous method should return a Task, and the caller should await it.'

Answer (score 0):

first add this code in photo to page 
[image]

then Correction code is

```
public static async Task<string> PUT(int id, string name, string code)
{
    var inputData = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"name", name },
        {"code", code }
    };
    var input= new StringContent(inputData.ToString());
   
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage res = await client.PutAsync("http://197.253.124.132:84/api/Departments/?id=" + id, input))
        {
            using (HttpContent content = res.Content)
            {
                string data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                if (data != null)
                {
                    return data;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return string.Empty;
}

public async void btnproperties_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var response = await PUT(int.Parse(txtid.text), txtname.text, txtcode.text);
    lblmessage.Text = (response);
}
```

Comment: Hello Iman, Please can you write the whole PUT method for me. I have 3 textboxes that i want to use its values to update the databae

Comment: just you want update db by this textboxes in c#?you want by ado.net or entityframwork?

Comment: Iman, I have an API that i am consuming. The table structure in the API has three columns that is ID,NAME,CODE. So on my asp.net webform i have three textboxes (txtid,txtName and txtCode) so upon click button i want to update the database record by calling the webAPI using the values in the textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

in the api side in controller write this code below
if use from asp.net core web api

```
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/Departments")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult update(int id,string name, string code)
    {
            var tbc = db.your_table.Where(x => x.id== id).FirstOrDefault();                   
            if (tbc==null)
            {
                return Problem("meesage:id Does not exist", "", 500);
            }
            else
            {
                tbc.id = id;
                tbc.name = name;
                tbc.code =code ;

                try
                {
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return Ok();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return Problem("message:Error", "", 500);
                }
            }
              
    }
```

if use from asp.net web api

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Departments")]
    public IHttpActionResult update(int id,string name, string code)
    {
    
            int stnew = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("update yourdb set name='"+name+"',code='"+code+"' where id="+id+"");
            if (stnew == 1)
            {
                return Ok(new { state = "ok" });
            }
            else
            {
                return Ok(new { state = "notok" });
            }
    }
```

final in webform write this code below

```
protected async void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://197.253.124.132:84/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/Departments/?id='"+txtid.Text+"'&name='"+txtname.Text+"'&code='"+txtcode.Text+"'");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {    
            //you can show result or you can show message as success 
            //var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            //lblmessage.Text = result.tostring();
            lblmessage.Text = "Update is Success";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello Iman, Am very grateful for your code. I have tried the code and the response status is 200 OK. but the record does not get updated. The database base values is still the same.The WEB API has a bearer Token which is eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoicmhlbWEiLCJqdGkiOiJhMjBhMzk3YS0zMzAwLTQ2OTEtYjkwNS03ZmJjOWE1NDU3NGUiLCJuYmYiOjE2MDI5NjAyOTMsImV4cCI6MTYwMzU2NTA5MywiaXNzIjoiUk1TLUFQSSIsImF1ZCI6IlJNUy1BUEkifQ.rqJywEkOJuVuqMvQn4L_H--hWEbQ1mKlCdj9_JXW5cs

Comment: use from asp.ner cor web api or asp.ner web api?

Comment: Can you please connect to the api with the bearer token and update the records and see where the issues is coming from

Comment: you must add [Authorize] to controller

Comment: if you dont know how to use jwt or token use this link:https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/11/aspnet-core-3-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api

Comment: Hello Iman, I have  consumed Get,Delete and Post Methods of the same API which works well. I have generated a Token and that is what am using. The API was developed by my course mate and am just consuming the method. But from your code am not seeing PUTASYNC what i see is GETASYNC. I rather want to update not to insert or post. Thanks

Comment: You can use the get method to send a text request and receive an answer